# how to convert user defined data type to hashset c#

Tags: c#, hashset

I have user defined type `Items` which inherits `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`. How to convert this type to `HashSet<Items>`. I am using below snippet, is there any efficient way to this?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool AddRange<T>(this HashSet<T> @this, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        bool allAdded = true;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            added &= @this.Add(item);
        }
        return allAdded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `HashSet<T>` has a constructor which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` and instantiates that HashSet from the collection. You could simply call that.

If you want to load the items in your custom type into an *existing* HashSet, you'd probably want to use the HashSet's [`UnionWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which:

> Modifies the current HashSet object to contain all elements that are present in itself, the specified collection, or both.

What these two options won't do, however, is give you a result specifying if any items didn't make it through the conversion. You'd be able to do it later, though, by calling one of HashSet's other methods, such as `IsSupersetOf`, or simply comparing Counts.